# What happens if I write to a device other than a disk?

Tags: linux, dd

I know, I can write to a hard disk just using `dd` command in Linux, such as `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`.

Since, every device is represented as file in Linux, I wonder what might happen if I intentionally or accidentally write to the audio device or any other device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the device.
A user program, when granted access, writes to the device's *data* interface.
There's also a *control* interface to the device, which is utilized by the device driver or by *ioctl()* calls from the user program.

Normally *data* written to a device cannot affect its *control*, but there are exceptions such as *ESCape control sequences* (used by printers and display terminals).  Such devices have a simple or no HW control interface (e.g. perhaps a 3-wire serial connection), and sharing the *data* and *control* channel is necessary.

Such devices typically use ASCII-coded *data*, and a *control sequence* uses the ASCII ESC character as a prefix.  Binary data (instead of ASCII text) will probably contain occasional bytes of decimal value 27, so that the subsequent bytes would be treated as a *control* sequence.  So garbage *data* sent to such a device will produce unpredictable operation.

Other devices, such as audio devices and storage drives, have a much more sophisticated *control* interface or a protocol for its shared *data* & *control* channel (e.g. ATAPI protocol for ATA drives).  *Data* written to the device is always clearly marked as and handled as *data*, and will not affect the device's operation.  Of course, sending garbage data would clobber stored data somewhere on a disk drive.  Or output high slew rates (e.g. square waves) to a speaker connected to the audio device.

Writing `/dev/zero` to an audio device will probably produce maximum negative DC voltage to the speaker, which will sound like a thunk then silence.  (Values to the DAC usually use biased representation; 0x8000 is a 16-bit value for zero volts.)   Prolonged output may overheat the audio amplifier and speaker's voice coil.

Access to a device's firmware (for rewriting) is typically a protected operation.  This would be true for *char* and *block* devices.

The previous comments refer to actual HW devices.  Writing garbage to special device files such as `/dev/mem` and `/dev/ports` will be unpredictable and not advised.

Answer (score 1):

You might erase data, corrupt memory, play some garbage on the sound device, etc... Not something you actually want to do.

For example:

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio
```

Wil play some random noise on the audio device (at least it did in the old times).

Comment: Can I damage my device by doing so, I mean can i write to the device firmware?

Comment: I think that would be unlikely, since device firmware is *usually* not directly exposed to the operating system (there are some devices that present themselves as a block device that contains a firmware file on it - in that case you could overwrite it by accident)